# Intersection Observer trigger when element is visible (before scrolling)

Tags: javascript, webapi, intersection-observer

I am trying to work with the Intersection Observer API. I have a function which works in my first iteration. The basic logic is that if the user scrolls down and adds or removes items from a basket, once the basket is in view again (as it is at the top of the document) then I fire an API call.

The issue is that it will not fire the function before scrolling, I want to trigger it if the item is visible or becomes visible again after scrolling (the second part is working)

Here is original js:

```
var observerTargets = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="mini-trolley"]');
var observerOptions = {
    root: null, // null means root is viewport
    rootMargin: '0px',
    threshold: 0.01 // trigger callback when 1% of the element is visible
}
var activeClass = 'active';
var trigger = $('button');
var isCartItemClicked = false;

trigger.on('click', function() {
    isCartItemClicked = true;
});

function observerCallback(entries, observer) { 
    entries.forEach(entry => {
        if(entry.isIntersecting && isCartItemClicked){
            $(observerTargets).removeClass(activeClass);
            $(entry.target).addClass(activeClass);
            isCartItemClicked = false;
            console.log('isCartItemClicked and in view');
            // do my api call function here
        } else {
            $(entry.target).removeClass(activeClass);
        }
    });
}

var observer = new IntersectionObserver(observerCallback, observerOptions);
[...observerTargets].forEach(target => observer.observe(target));
```

I have updated this so it now checks if the item is visible. so I have updated:

`if(entry.isIntersecting && isCartItemClicked)`

to

`if((entry.isVisible || entry.isIntersecting) && isCartItemClicked)`

The issue as I understand is that the observer is only triggered on scroll, but the entry.isVisible is part of the observer callback function.

I have made a [JSFIDDLE here](http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/unfhkagr/) (which has HTML and CSS markup).

Is it possible to modify the code. Weirdly the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) does not mention the isVisible property, but it is clearly part of the function.

[image]

Comment: entry.isVisible is in proposal draft and is currently supported by only Chrome. https://web.dev/intersectionobserver-v2/ . I'm not sure about the working of `isVisible` but I believe it returns if the element to be observed is visible in viewport or not (opacity > 0, and not covered by any other element).

Comment: ah OK, well that means I need another method, something like viewport offset top greater than cart item height.

Comment: Yah, you can use the BoundingClientRect maybe to check that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is a little tricky but can be done by creating a `someObserverEntriesVisible` parameter that is set by the `observerCallback`. With that in place we can define how the button triggers should be handled separately from the observer callback for each intersecting entry.

```js
const observerTargets = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="mini-trolley"]');
const observerOptions = {
    root: null, // null means root is viewport
    rootMargin: '0px',
    threshold: 0.01 // trigger callback when 1% of the element is visible
};
const activeClass = 'active';
const trigger = $('button');

let isCartItemClicked = false;
let someObserverEntriesVisible = null;
let observerEntries = [];

trigger.on('click', () => {
    isCartItemClicked = true;
    if (someObserverEntriesVisible) {
        console.log('fired from button');
        observerCallback(observerEntries, observer, false);
    }
});

function observerCallback(entries, observer, resetCartItemClicked = true) {
    observerEntries = entries;
    someObserverEntriesVisible = false;
    entries.forEach(entry => {
        someObserverEntriesVisible ||= entry.isIntersecting;
        if (entry.isIntersecting && isCartItemClicked) {
            $(entry.target).addClass(activeClass);
            // add API call here
            if (resetCartItemClicked) {
                isCartItemClicked = false;
                console.log('fired from observer');
            }
        } else {
            $(entry.target).removeClass(activeClass);
        }
    });
}

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(observerCallback, observerOptions);
[...observerTargets].forEach(target => observer.observe(target));
```

```css
#content {
  height: 500px;
}

.active {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mini-trolley">Observer target1</div>
<button>Top button</button>
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="mini-trolley">Observer target2</div>
<button>Bottom button</button>
```

Comment: This looks great, I am going to try and implement it soon, and feedback. Thank you.

Comment: @lharby Made one additional adjustment. I noticed that from button trigger all entries were being sent to `handleCartVisibleAndItemClicked`, rather than the visible ones. Added a function to filter to just the visible elements.

Comment: @lharby I just noticed a simplification here. If you store the entries from observerCallback, you can reference them directly from the button. This lets us clean up quite a bit of code so that it's now just the trigger click handler and the observerCallback.

Comment: OK cool, you have edited yes? I think this is not right :D 
`visible ||= entry.isIntersecting;` I guess should be `visible || entry.isIntersecting;`

Comment: Nope, that's correct. It's roughly equivalent to `visible = visible || entry.isIntersecting;` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR_assignment). It means the same thing, just a little more concise.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks I have never used it. I can't give you any more points, but thank you for making the code more succinct.

Comment: Happy to help :)